# Android send data on RFCOMM socket

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, rfcomm, spp

I'm interfacing a bluetooth medical device with my Android app.
So, I created a communication channel RFCOMM (SPP protocol) because the medical device allow SSP communication protocol.
The device guide give me the structure of the command to send on SPP protocol. e.g. 0x02 0x70 0x04 0x0A that represent a simple 4-bytes command). 
So, I need to send command like this (compliant with the SPP protocol).

After the creation of the `BluetoothSocket` i get the input and output streams (following this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html)) in this manner:

```
  InputStream iStream = null;
  iStream = socket.getInputStream(); // socket is my BluetoothSocket object
  OutputStream oStream = null;
  oStream = socket.getOutputStream();
```

What can I do at this poit in order for send the command represented from the hexadecimal sequence 0x02 0x70 0x04 0x0A ?

Comment: Why dont you just call the `write()` method from the `oStream` object? I guess that this method supports writing bytes to the socket.

Answer (score 0):

You can use write on the OutputStream to write byte arrays.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{ 0x02,0x70,0x04,0x0A };
oStream.write(bytes);
```